# Does not download a file by magnet links

Tags: javascript, webtorrent

This is an example from the documentation.

```js
var client = new WebTorrent()

var torrentId = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:08ada5a7a6183aae1e09d831df6748d566095a10&dn=Sintel&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.empire-js.us%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2F&xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fsintel.torrent'

client.add(torrentId, function (torrent) {
  // Torrents can contain many files. Let's use the .mp4 file
  //var file = torrent.files.find(function (file) {
  //return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
  //})
  // no console.log !!
  console.log(torrent)
  // Display the file by adding it to the DOM. Supports video, audio, image, etc. files
  torrent.files[0].appendTo('body')
})
```

An example works well.
But if I change the magnet link to another but nothing happens.
The link to which I am changing is valid.

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:C45CE38E4508E775E49EB2A6841C814D1A8AD375&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt3.t-ru.org%2Fann%3Fmagnet
```

but does not work with this link. Not a single mistake or nothing at all

Comment: There is no other peers. The changed magnet link has no webtorrent tracker(s) (`...&tr=wss...`) and even if some are added, it won't help because that torrent almost certainly only has BitTorrent peers. Frankly, it's hard to find a swarm with webtorrent peers because webtorrent was a bad idea in the first place and almost no one uses it.

Comment: Now you can upvote, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar issues recently trying to work this out. Only instant.io (using a turn server) consistently works. Very little `webRTC` stuff works for me.

I think the reason the template provided by `WebTorrent` works and no others is because the model contains a magnet which has a link to the torrent file on their website.

I suspect they are seeding it or even just providing it via some other means.

`xs=https%3A%2F%2Fwebtorrent.io%2Ftorrents%2Fsintel.torrent`

Whoever created instant.io took the web torrent template and made it work. `WebRTC` is an absolute nightmare, and the web torrent template/site doesn't even get the `WebSocket` connections right (for me, at least).

If you are looking to pass on relatively small amounts of data, then relaying via your `WebSockets` is far more manageable.

If you want to create something like `WebTorrent`, that works look at instant.io's Github. You'll need to set up a server and configure a turn server. `WebRTC` is like trying to configure a graphics card in 1992. Good luck.